# rxjs observable not created

Tags: angular, observable

I have a simple angular 2 service like this:

```
let ws = new WebSocket(url);

let observable = Observable.create((obs: Observer<MessageEvent>) => {

  console.log('create')

  ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
  ws.onerror   = obs.error.bind(obs);
  ws.onclose   = obs.complete.bind(obs);

  return ws.close.bind(ws);
});
```

The problem is that the callbackfunction is never getting called. The log output of `create` is never executed. Any idea what I could have done wrong?

Comment: There is already a function in `RxJS` that makes an observable from web socket connection, so you don't need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are not subscribing to the observable you created. Working code:

```js
const {
  Observable
} = Rx;

let ws = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org");

let observable = Observable.create((obs) => {
  console.log('create')

  setInterval(() => {
    ws.send("ping");
  }, 2000);

  ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
  ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
  ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);

  return ws.close.bind(ws);
});

let ws$ = observable.subscribe({
  next: (val) => {
    console.log("Observable emits: " + val.data)
  },
  complete: (val) => {
    console.log("Observable complete")
  },
  error: (val) => {
    console.log("Observable error")
  },
});

setTimeout(() => {
  ws$.unsubscribe();
}, 10000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```